# How do I prove the combining of errors with the following formula?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am given that

$\text{var}(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{\partial h}{\partial X_i})^2 \ \sigma_i^2$

and with this I need to prove that:

1. $\sigma(X+Y) = \sqrt{\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2}$
2. $\lambda$ = $\frac{\sigma}{|\overline{x}|}$
3. $\lambda(XY)$ = $\sqrt{\lambda_x^2 + \lambda_y^2}$
4. $\lambda_x$$^{\alpha}$ = $|\alpha| \ \lambda_x$

where

- $\sigma$ is the standard error
- $\lambda$ is the fractional standard error
- X, Y are independent variables
- h is a function, $h(X_1, X_2, ... , X_i)$ of random variables
- $\sigma_i^2 = \text{var}(X_i)$

I do not know where to begin, I'm assuming that:

$\text{var}(X+Y) = \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{\partial (X+Y)}{\partial X_i})^2 \ \sigma_x^2$ + $\sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{\partial (X+Y)}{\partial X_i})^2 \ \sigma_y^2$

but I do not know where to go from here. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You started well, but I think you don't understand what that formula means. In the first formula, $h$ is a function of some variables $X_i$. In your formula you have renamed them to $X=X_1$ and $Y=X_2$. The sum is not from $1$ to $2$, but instead the sum is over $X$ and $Y$. This means that you should write
$$\begin{align}\text{var}(X+Y) &= \left(\frac{\partial (X+Y)}{\partial X}\right)^2 \ \sigma_x^2 + \left(\frac{\partial (X+Y)}{\partial Y}\right)^2 \ \sigma_y^2\\&=1^2\sigma_x^2+1^2\sigma_y^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks mate. How would I prove conditions 2, 3 and 4 using the formula?

Comment: I think 2 is the definition. Then $\lambda(XY)=\frac{\sqrt{\text{var} XY}}{XY}$. Then, calculating $\text{var} XY=Y^2\sigma_X^2+X^2\sigma_y^2$ from the definition will give you the desired result. Similarly, you can do it for 4.